# Using Jquery to dynamically create Divs with Buttons that have a function to close the div

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am trying to create new divs of a fruit, but I am added an X to help call a special function that will delete it. My only problems is when I dynamically create my div+span I end up with problems when I try to use the onclick function

Here is my HTML code

```
<html>
    <div id="listContents">

    </div>
</html>
```

Also below is my script code

```
    list = ["apple", "strawberry", "banana"]
for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
    $("#listContents").append('<div>' + list[i] + '<span class="picker" id="close" onclick="removeFruit(list[i].toString())"> (X)</span></div>');
}


function removeFruit(fruit){
    console.log("Here is the fruit you selected");
}
```

Obviously I want to be able to delete these when the X button is clicked but right now I am having trouble getting the onclick function to work correctly. Also here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g92djb1n/2/) I quickly made

Comment: In the onclick attribute you're passing the literal string `"removeFruit(list[i].toString())"`, you need to interpolate the string like this `"removeFruit(" + list[i] + ")"`
Also, there's no need to do `.toString()` since the values are already strings

Comment: @MaxiDiaz I just tried your method but my console is giving me this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input` with my sources showing `removeFruit(` I just updated my jsfiddle to reflect your suggestion

Comment: Please, keep consistency in the quotes or double quotes when defining the string. In your case it is with single quotes. Try this `$("#listContents").append('<div>' + list[i] + '<span class="picker" id="close" onclick="removeFruit(' + list[i] + ')"> (X)</span></div>');`

Comment: @MaxiDiaz yes  i was just playing around with the quotation and noticed i need a single quotation mark and and need to add `\'` too .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating an `span` with id `close` for each item in your list. Ids should be unique throughout the whole document. Since you are not using the id attribute, I suggest you delete it.

Also, you are appending an `onclick` event in all your `span` items. I would use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

Furthermore, since you are converting the elements in your array into HTML elements, you could use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to do the transformation and generate all the HTML for your items.

Lastly, you can add a data attribute to account for the item index. You can then read that attribute using jQuery [`data`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method.

Having that into account, the code could look like:

```
var list = ["apple", "strawberry", "banana"];
var $list = $("#listContents");
$list.on('click', '.picker', function(ev) {
    var idx = $(ev.target).data('idx');
    removeFruit(list[idx]);
});

$list.append(list.map(function(item, idx) {
    return '<div>' + item + '<span class="picker" data-idx="' + idx + '"> (X)</span></div>';
}).join(''));

function removeFruit(fruit) {
    console.log("Here is the fruit you selected");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what others are saying, `id` should be reserved for only one-time use.

Also, when you are dynamically creating the items you give each `onClick` the string `"removeFruit(list[i].toString())"` so it is not actually looking for a function called removeFruit but instead it has the actual string "removeFruit".

When creating the `html` you could instead give each item a `fruitName` attribute equal to the fruit name like so.

```
list = ["apple", "strawberry", "banana"]
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            $("#listContents").append('<div>' + list[i] + '<span class="picker" fruitName='+ list[i] + '>(X)</span></div>');
        }
```

and then we can target these using a click listener rather than an `onClick` and use what `fruitName` is equal to by using the `$(this).attr('fruitName')`.

```
$("#listContents").on('click', '.picker', function(e) {
            removeFruit($(this).attr('fruitName'))
        })


        function removeFruit(fruit) {
            console.log('You clicked ' + fruit);
        }
```

`$(this)` will reffer to whichever span you clicked on and the `.attr()` will look for the `fruitName` and find what it is equal to.

Answer (score 0):

you could add the id while you are doing the map.

```js
["apple", "strawberry", "banana"].map(x => {
  $("#listContents").append(`<div id="${x}"> 
           ${x}
                                <span 
                                  class="picker"
                                   onclick="(() => document.getElementById('${x}').remove())()">
                                  (X)
                                  </span>
                                </div>`)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="listContents">
```